# How can I infinite loop files in a directory in Autohotkey?

Tags: loops, autohotkey

I currently have a script doing a directory loop over images. How can I make it infinite?

```
#NoTrayIcon
Loop, img\*.*
{
    SplashImage, %A_LoopFileShortPath%
    Sleep, 1000
    SplashImage, Off
    Sleep, 1000 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Always use AutoHotkey from http://ahkscript.org/ (current version, new official website)! AutoHotkey from autohotkey.com is outdated!*

What you mean by infinite? If you mean to start again when it goes through every file, then the best way to do that is to add another `Loop` . Here is a code:

```
#NoTrayIcon
Loop
{
Loop, img\*.*
{
    SplashImage, %A_LoopFileShortPath%
    Sleep, 1000
    SplashImage, Off
    Sleep, 1000 
}
}
```

If the code above is not working for some reason for you even after installing newest version of AutoHotkey from http://ahkscript.org/ then use version below:

```
#NoTrayIcon
StartLabel:
Loop, img\*.*
{
    SplashImage, %A_LoopFileShortPath%
    Sleep, 1000
    SplashImage, Off
    Sleep, 1000 
}
Goto, StartLabel
```

Comment: I actually tried that and it didn't work. I read from some users that it doesn't handle nested loops.

Comment: honestinjun, vasili111's code works without any issue for me. It sounds like you're probably having an issue elsewhere, possibly due to your working directory. Try using the full folder name instead of "img\" and see if you're still having problems.

Comment: @honestinjun Which version of Autohotkey are you using? Always use AutoHotkey from http://ahkscript.org/ (current version, new official website). AutoHotkey from autohotkey.com is outdated (dont use it)!

Comment: @honestinjun Also check second version of the script.

Comment: ahkscript.org and autohotkey.com are now the same: https://www.autohotkey.com/foundation/history.html

Comment: @JohnY I know that, you are right, now they are same. In old times (it was like yesterday, time is flying with speed of light, but anyway ;)) it was not so, so I needed to indicate in all my AutoHotkey posts that people use right version, because at that times  autohotkey.com was distributing outdated version of AutoHotkey. Some of my posts I already edited but it seems that some may be left. Thank you for making corrections. P.S. AutoHotkey has one of the greatest community I ever have seen!